# REST API to Redux State - Separate API endpoint for Redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, redux, flux

I have an API which returns an array of objects which it gets from MongoDB.

API:

```
[
  { _id: b23a, title: "Some Title" },
  { _id: c10x, title: "Some Other Title" },
  { _id: a31w, title: "And even more" },
]
```

The array is in order. I would like to preserve this order in my Redux state, however, I would also like to be able to access all objects by id. So I thought of organizing my state in the following way:

```
{
  order: ["b23a","c10x","a31w"], //keeps the order
  byId: {
    "b23a" : { _id: b23a, title: "Some Title" },
    "c10x" : { _id: c10x, title: "Some Other Title" },
    "a31w" : { _id: a31w, title: "And even more" },
  }
}
```

What is the best way to go about this? Would it be better to have a separate API route which sends back the data in the exact form I need for Redux? So I would then *modify the data on the server side before sending it back* and then just put it into my Redux state; Or: is it more common / more efficient to *parse the array on the client side*? What would you normally recommend?

Comment: You are already having the order in byID as keys. Why do you want to store order in another key.

Comment: sorry that's just in the example. The ids will be generated by mongodb, so there will be no order. I have changed the example now.

Comment: It depends on many parameters, how your data scales, what is the final goal of parsing this array, is there already limit/pagination ordering/filtering server side, how many times do you refresh these data... The choice you'll make will be based on performance optimisation. (btw you probably don't need to parse your array like that)

Comment: what do you mean by `btw you probably don't need to parse your array like that` ?

Answer (score 0):

`MongoDB` ids doesn't guarantee the `order`. If you want the insertion order create a `date` field and get the results sorted by `date` field in `MongoDb`

If you are trying to order the `objects` based on the `title` it's quite simple and I would suggest you do in client side. If you are using a library like `Lodash` it's quite simple and you don't have to preserve the order too. With `lodash` you could do this.

```
data = _.orderBy(array_of_objects, ['title']);
```

Comment: i don't want to order by title, but the array already holds the order i need. so i would just need to convert my array into the redux state format. The question is whether I should do this conversion client side, or whether I already convert on the server and then have a separate endpoint that sends back the data in exactly the format I need for my Redux state.

Comment: @R.Kohlisch your requirement is simple. Do not create seperate endpoints just for the sake of order. Do it on server side ordered by insertion date and get the results  and create the structure on the client side.

Comment: You edited your answer, which I appreciate, but you seem to misunderstand me. I do not say that MongoDB ids create order, nor do I need anything ordered. The array is ordered. My question is only about where one would usually parse my array structure into the structure required for my Redux state.